# How to pass data from a parent blade to a included modal?

Tags: php, html, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to call a modal on a button click and pass through an `$incident` array, which will then be passed through the properties of a Vue component. How do you pass through data from a parent blade through to an included modal? i tried using data-attach but i think that is wrong.

I currently have a table looping through an incidents array passed through to my blade:

```
@foreach($incidents as $incident)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $incident->service_now_incident_number }}</td>
        <td>{{ $incident->business_service_reference ?: 'N/A' }}</td>
        <td>{{ $incident->status }}</td>
        <td>{{ $incident->raised_date->format('d/m/y') }}</td>
        <td>{{ $incident->email }}</td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#incident-details-modal" data-attach="{{$incident}}">View</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

This is the modal i am trying to pass data to:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="incident-details-modal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <incident-details :incident="{{$incident}}"></incident-details>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

is there a way i can pass through array data on modal load?

Comment: You are mixing concepts here. Why are you using VueJS and blade at the same time? The point of some frontend framework is to make sure the frontend and the backend are "independent" and separated. The communication could be made with REST.

Comment: great answer there pal cheers.

Answer (score -2):

You can use $emit method for this purpose.
v-on directive captures the child components events that is emitted by $emit

Child component triggers clicked event:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    onClickButton (event) {
      this.$emit('clicked', 'someValue')
    }
  }
}
```

Parent component receive clicked event:

```
<div>
  <child @clicked="onClickChild"></child>
</div>

export default {
  methods: {
    onClickChild (value) {
      console.log(value) // someValue
    }
  }
}
```